# Unable to get user's top artists and tracks with Spotify API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spotify, fetch-api

Learning the Spotify API and have been able to access all end points except this one through react. Here is the code I have left in my (incorrect) solution.

```
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists', {
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.items));
```

This is in a componentDidMount method in my React app. Any ideas, other approaches I should be taking to getting this to work properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No, I am not receiving any information to suggest that the fetch was successful or unsuccessful. But I also don't believe that it returns any data.

Comment: did you check your network request?